# Archive all the files from source directory into a xyz.gz file and move that to target directory using UNIX shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gzip, archive

Requirement: Archive files using UNIX shell script into .gz format without directory structure

I am using below command

```
tar -C source_dir -zcvf target_dir/xyz.gz source_dir
```

example:

```
tar -C /home/log -zcvf /home/archive/xyz.gz /home/log
```

here `xyz.gz` contains `/home/log`

It's creating `xyz.gz` file maintaining the directory structure. I want only files to be archive without directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following command:

```
$ cd /home/log

$ tar zcvf /home/archive/xyz.gz *
```

Comment: Note that a four-space prefix on a line renders console I/O in a code block, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks 
This is working for current Directory means from "/home/log".
What if I want to run this command from other path like "/home/usr/script"

Comment: one change in requirement. Instead of creating a single archive file for all log files, I want to create individual .gz files for all logs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--transform` option to strip leading path components from the archived file names using a `sed` espression:

```
tar -C /home/log -zcvf /home/archive/xyz.gz --transform 's_.*/__' /home/log
```

This however will also write an entry for each encountered directory. If you don't want that, you can use `find` to find only regular files and pass them to tar on stdin like this:

```
cd /home/log
find -type f -print0 | tar -zcvf /home/archive/xyz.gz --transform 's_.*/__' --verbatim-files-from --null -T -
```

Note that this may create multiple entries with the same name in the tar archive, if files with the same name exist in different subdirectories. Also you should probably use the conventional `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` extension for the compressed tar archive.